# MacBook Pro (2012 - MD101LL/A): Superdrive to SSD swap?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, dvd

Does anyone know if it's possible to swap out the "Superdrive" optical drive on this model and replace it with an SSD?

Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.5 13" (Identifiers: Mid-2012 13" - MD101LL/A)

Basically, I am hoping to put two SSD drives into this, using one SSD drive as a windows install (*kinda ghastly* i know - yet, game dev software). With the RAM maxed out and  dual SSD drives, opinions on as to whether this model would be fast enough to run Unity, Second Life, 3d Studio Max, etc…

Comment: You may want to trial Parallels Desktop, VMWare or whatnot to see how you like running Windows virtualized under OS X. On my stone-age MacBook4,1, Parallels runs Windows better than Boot Camp by a significant margin. Max RAM and an SSD go a long way to making VMs perform well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to replace the optical drive with hard drive / SSD. 
You can follow this [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive/13787).